# Why is my CustomAdapter not being used?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I created a class called FTPSite with getters and setters for name,address,username,password,port,passive mode. I'm trying to create site manager by using a custom adapter to show the site names however I'm just getting the package name and numbers as my list item.

```
public class SiteManager extends Activity {
    DBAdapter myDb;
    public FTPClient mFTPClient = null;

    public EditText sitename;
    public EditText address;
    public EditText username;
    public EditText password;
    public EditText port;
    public CheckBox passive;
    public ListView site_list;
    public TextView tview;
    public Button clr;
    public Button test;
    public Button savesite;
    public Button close;
    public Button connect;

    String _name;
    String _address;
    String _username;
    String _password;
    int _port;
    boolean _passive;
    List<FTPSite> model = new ArrayList<FTPSite>();
    SiteAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.site_manager);

        site_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.siteList);

        adapter = new SiteAdapter();
        site_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        sitename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogsitename);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogaddress);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogusername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogpassword);
        port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogport);
        passive = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dialogpassive);
        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);
        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
        clr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clrBtn);
        test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testBtn);

        test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                siteManager();
            }
        });
        savesite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveSite);
        savesite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                siteManager();
            }
        });
        openDb();
        displayRecords();
    }

    private void openDb() {
        myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
        myDb.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        closeDb();
    }

    private void closeDb() {
        myDb.close();
    }

    public void siteManager() {

        connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnResult = new Intent();
                returnResult.putExtra("ftpname", _name);
                returnResult.putExtra("ftpaddress", _address);
                returnResult.putExtra("ftpusername", _username);
                returnResult.putExtra("ftppassword", _password);
                returnResult.putExtra("ftpport", _port);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnResult);
                finish();

            }
        });

        close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _name = sitename.getText().toString();
                _address = address.getText().toString();
                _username = username.getText().toString();
                _password = password.getText().toString();
                _port = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
                _passive = false;
                if (passive.isChecked()) {
                    _passive = true;
                }

                boolean status = ftpConnect(_address, _username, _password,
                        _port);
                ftpDisconnect();

                if (status == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(SiteManager.this, "Connection Succesful",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    savesite.setVisibility(0);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SiteManager.this,
                            "Connection Failed:" + status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                }
            }
        });

        savesite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _name = sitename.getText().toString();
                _address = address.getText().toString();
                _username = username.getText().toString();
                _password = password.getText().toString();
                _port = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
                long newId = myDb.insertRow(_name, _address, _username,
                        _password, 21);
                FTPSite tmpSite = new FTPSite();
                tmpSite.setName(_name);
                tmpSite.setAddress(_address);
                tmpSite.setUsername(_username);
                tmpSite.setPassword(_password);
                tmpSite.setPort(_port);
                model.add(tmpSite);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(SiteManager.this, tmpSite.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Shows the correct name
                // displayRecords();
            }
        });

        clr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearAll();
            }
        });

    }

    public void displayRecords() {

        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
        // displayRecordSet(cursor);
    }

    protected void displayRecordSet(Cursor c) {
        String msg = "";

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int id = c.getInt(0);
                _name = c.getString(1);
                _address = c.getString(2);
                _username = c.getString(3);
                _password = c.getString(4);
                _port = c.getInt(5);

                msg += "id=" + id + "\n";
                msg += ", name=" + _name + "\n";
                msg += ", address=" + _address + "\n";
                msg += ", username=" + _username + "\n";
                msg += ", password=" + _password + "\n";
                msg += ", port=" + _port + "\n";

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }

    public void clearAll() {
        myDb.deleteAll();
    }

    public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password,
            int port) {
        try {
            mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
            // connecting to the host
            mFTPClient.connect(host, port);

            // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success
            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
                // login using username & password
                boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);

                mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                return status;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host );
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean ftpDisconnect() {
        try {
            mFTPClient.logout();
            mFTPClient.disconnect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d(TAG,
            // "Error occurred while disconnecting from ftp server.");
        }

        return false;
    }



class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FTPSite> {
            public SiteAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)    {
    super(context,resource,textViewResourceId,objects);  
}
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.siterow, null);
            }
            FTPSite s = model.get(position);
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(s.getName());

            return (row);
        }
    }


  FTPSite.java


    public class FTPSite {
        private String name = "";
        private String address = "";
        private String username = "";
        private String password = "";
        private int port = 21;
        private boolean passive = false;

        public FTPSite() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public String getName() {
            return (name);
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return (address);
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return (username);
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return (password);
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return (port);
        }

        public void setPort(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        public boolean isPassive() {
            return (passive);
        }

        public void setPassive(boolean passive) {
            this.passive = passive;
        }

    }
```

And my siterow.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    />
```

**EDIT**

```
List<FTPSite> model = new ArrayList<FTPSite>();
    ArrayAdapter<FTPSite> adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.site_manager);

        site_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.siteList);

        adapter = new SiteAdapter(SiteManager.this, R.layout.siterow,
                R.id.title, model);
        site_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        sitename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogsitename);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogaddress);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogusername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogpassword);
        port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogport);
        passive = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dialogpassive);
        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);
        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
        clr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clrBtn);
        test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testBtn);

        test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                siteManager();
            }
        });
        savesite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveSite);
        savesite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                siteManager();
            }
        });
        openDb();
        displayRecords();
    }

    private void openDb() {
        myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
        myDb.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        closeDb();
    }

    private void closeDb() {
        myDb.close();
    }

    public void siteManager() {

        connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnResult = new Intent();
                returnResult.putExtra("ftpname", _name);
                returnResult.putExtra("ftpaddress", _address);
                returnResult.putExtra("ftpusername", _username);
                returnResult.putExtra("ftppassword", _password);
                returnResult.putExtra("ftpport", _port);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnResult);
                finish();

            }
        });

        close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _name = sitename.getText().toString();
                _address = address.getText().toString();
                _username = username.getText().toString();
                _password = password.getText().toString();
                _port = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
                _passive = false;
                if (passive.isChecked()) {
                    _passive = true;
                }

                boolean status = ftpConnect(_address, _username, _password,
                        _port);
                ftpDisconnect();

                if (status == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(SiteManager.this, "Connection Succesful",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    savesite.setVisibility(0);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SiteManager.this,
                            "Connection Failed:" + status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                }
            }
        });

        savesite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _name = sitename.getText().toString();
                _address = address.getText().toString();
                _username = username.getText().toString();
                _password = password.getText().toString();
                _port = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
                long newId = myDb.insertRow(_name, _address, _username,
                        _password, 21);
                FTPSite tmpSite = new FTPSite();
                tmpSite.setName(_name);
                tmpSite.setAddress(_address);
                tmpSite.setUsername(_username);
                tmpSite.setPassword(_password);
                tmpSite.setPort(_port);
                model.add(tmpSite);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(SiteManager.this, tmpSite.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // displayRecords();
            }
        });

        clr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearAll();
            }
        });

    }

    class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FTPSite> {
        public SiteAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<FTPSite> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.siterow, null);
        }
        FTPSite s = model.get(position);
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(s.getName());

        return (row);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `SiteAdapter adapter;`

with

`ArrayAdapter<FTPSite> adapter`

then in your adapter class you need to create a constructor like this

```
public SiteAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)    {
    super(context,resource,textViewResourceId,objects);  
}
```

see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

EDIT:

when you declare you need to do

```
adapter = new SiteAdapter(this,r.layout.your_layout,new int[] {r.id.title},model);
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I made the changes but am not seeing any difference.

Comment: no you didnt make the changes. Where you declare your adapter as a class wide variable with `SiteAdapter adapter;` is wrong. it needs to be `ArrayAdapter<FTPSite> adapter`

Comment: Ahh ok going o try that declaration

Comment: What is the new int[] argument? I get The constructor SiteManager.SiteAdapter(SiteManager, int, int[], List<FTPSite>) is undefined

Comment: its an array of the id's in your layout, since you only have one you just do `new int[] {r.id.title}` like i did in my answer